# How to disable color conversion in Imagemagick

Tags: image, imagemagick, ghostscript

I'm using Imagemagick for converting PDF to a raster image! The command that I am running is  `convert.exe -verbose -density 600 +antialias "E:\sample pdf\sample50 B.pdf" -quality 100 "D:\sample50_2.png"`

Now the problem that I'm having is that the color on the PDF is not the same on the generated image. So what is the problem? I think the problem might be because of -dUseCIEColor. It is the only odd thing. I used "-dNOPSICC" to disable the loading of CIE, but it didn't work!!! What do you guys think is the problem!? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is, almost certainly, to make an example file available. I very much doubt that the problem is colour conversion, except in as much as the PDF might be in CMYK space and I believe PNG doesn't support that, so you will **have** to convert the CMYK to RGB.

In that case there are *many* options for controlling the conversion, provided you are using a recent version of Ghostscript (you don't state the version), but -dUseCIEColor is the **first** thing you should remove. That's an archaic version of PostScript coloru management that only works well if you know **exactly** how to use it. Since you aren't supplying a CRD that's clearly not the case, so remove it, it will only do harm.

-dNOPSICC only works for PostScript, since your input file is a PDF, its not going to have any effect. You can't prevent loading ICC profiles from a PDF file, they are always honoured. In any event that would only imrove the colour quality anyway :-)

I'd also suggest that you use Ghostscript directly rather than going through convert, at least initially, because that removes a layer of obfuscation, means I can reproduce your command line, and ensures there are no controls being set 'behind the scenes'.

Comment: Thank you, -dUseCIEColor was the problem. Resolved it using -doNotApply. :)

Comment: Your PDF is likely CMYK and would need to be converted to sRGB. So add -colorspace sRGB befor reading the PDF. (Use -colorspace RGB on very old versions of IM). Note that +antialias is not relevant there. If you want higher detail, then you should use a larger density value and then resize to the pixel dimensions you want. Also -quality values mean something totally different for PNG than for JPG. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality. If using -colorspace sRGB before your PDF does not help. Then you could use profiles for more accurate color conversion.

Comment: Yep my PDF is CYMK! and actually +antialias really helps me a lot my removing smoothing, i really need the pics sharp. if i increase my density the file size becomes **humongous**  . Can you tell me where to place the colorspace option so that the image gets generated  as same as the PDF?  Thank you very much for your support! :)